# Android Firebase - Is it possible to use limitToFirst()/limitToLast() in between startAt() and endAt()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to have its query something like this

```
postRef
   .orderByChild("dateCreated")
   .startAt(startDate)
   .limitToFirst(5)
   .endAt(endDate)
```

Comment: Seems possible. Are you having a problem with it? (Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270933/should-i-answer-is-it-possible-type-of-questions)

Answer (score 1):

I have always used limitToLast in the end.

```
Query query=mDatabase.getReference().child("posts").orderByChild("date").limitToLast(1);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Take a look at this link maybe you will find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

But, for better code comprehension you should define the range of your search first, and then limit the results count.

```
postRef.orderByChild("dateCreated").startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate).limitToFirst(5)
```